# dd() on laravel doesn't echo out

Tags: php, laravel

My routes.php

```
    <?php

Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']] , function() {
    route::get('/' , [
        'as' => 'home',
        'uses' => 'HomeController@index',
        ]);
    Route::post('/' , [
        'uses' => 'HomeController@create',
        ]);
});
```

and HomeController.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return '<form action="'. route('home') .'" method="post"><input type="text" name="email"><input type="submit"></form>';
    }
    public function create(Request $request) {
        dd($request->email);
    }
}
```

its a form with an input name 'email'  , and when i enter my email it should show me the email i have just entered , its gives me a blank page instead.

Answer (score 1):

try

```
dd($request->all()) or dd($request->input('email')
```

Comment: dd($request->all()); ,   dd($request->input('email')); giving me a blank page too :/

Comment: check you route file, the first get route must be `Route` and not `route`, try again replacing it

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong action in the form

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Http\Requests;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    public function index() {
        return '<form action="{{action('HomeController@create')}}" method="post"><input type="text" name="email"><input type="submit"></form>';
    }
    public function create(Request $request) {
        dd($request->email);
    }
}
```

Also, make sure to place the CSRF token in your forms, if you have the middleware enabled.